# How to do a GET in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, get

I wish to get a file from a website using Javascript. This file has strings written on each line that I wish to get access to, using AJAX. I wish to store these strings in an array. How would I go about doing this request?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for your question! However, this is not really the kind of question that Stack Overflow is here to answer. [Read this for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) Once you have a specific question about a specific problem you are having with code you are writing, feel free to return.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start reading up on jquery and the 'get' function:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

1. Load the file
2. Split it by line
3. Load the urls
4. Run code

---

```
$.get('file.txt', function(data) {
    var urls = data.split('\n');
    $.each(urls, function(i, val){
         // add url to queue and load each
    })
});
```

Comment: the question is not about jQuery

Comment: @JanTuroň This question isn't really about anything. The answer could be: `I would make a function that does that for me.`

Answer (score 0):

To extend [slinky2000's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16719095/how-to-do-a-get-in-javascript/16719139#16719139)

```
$.get('file.txt', function(file) {
    var strings = file.split('\n');
    // strings is an array here:
    console.log(strings);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function loadXMLDoc() {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "yourfile.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

but you should use Jquery, it better than using Javascript by its self. It does a get request for you and it is Ajax.

Follow this, it should be a breeze

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/